# How to show the Index page with its controller name itself in MVC3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, routes

I have written the code like this below

```
 public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );

    }
```

This code makes all the Index pages viewable even call its controller name.. For example: A controller called "Communication" having view called "Index". In this situation, i can call only the controller name enough to see the Index page "http://localhost:10595/CommunicationCenter".. This URL enough to show the Index page available inside CommunicationCenter controller. This is right scenario for me.. But "http://localhost:10595/" alone should go to Login page.. If i rewritten the above code like this

```
 public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Account", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );

    }
```

Then "http://localhost:10595/" this URL alone working that it shows the Login page.. But this code fails on showing the Index page inside controller name itself.. I have tried to use two MapRoute().. But first one only get executed.. I couldn't achieve both scenario.. So please help me as soon as possible

Comment: I suspect your not taking the right approach. The default should not be `/Account/Login`. Your other controllers should have the `[Authorize]` attribute, so if the user is not authorized, they are automatically redirected to the login page, and if successful, then redirected back to the default page

Comment: If the Default should be "/Account/Login", then only it shows the login page while hitting the domain name in the server.. So i wanted it as Default

Comment: I don't understand why you want the default to be `/Account/Login`? Typically the default is `Home/Index` (i.e. the standard default route) so when you go to `http://localhost:10595/` it will automatically redirect to `/Account/Login` if the user is not authorized.

Comment: Initially When user get into site, i need to show the Login page to check whether authorized or not.. But http://localhost:10595/ is not redirecting to /Account/Login page.. Thats the problem i am facing

Comment: No you dont. If the Index method of the Home controller has the `[Authorize]` attribute, then the user is automatically redirected to the login page (that's what the `AuthorizeAttribute` does)